# Can't debug Android crash when calling glCreateProgram

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm trying to port a game of mine over to Android. So far I've compiled all of the dependencies to .so files, including my game engine code, and then I've linked to these shared libraries from the main application.

When I launch the application through the emulator, the program starts to load but crashes in a call to glCreateProgram:

```
I/DEBUG   (   34): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic:4.3/JB_MR2/774058:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (   34): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   (   34): pid: 873, tid: 900, name: UNKNOWN  >>> com.indgames.rocks <<<
I/DEBUG   (   34): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000048
I/DEBUG   (   34):     r0 00000048  r1 00000001  r2 4d95ea24  r3 00000004
I/DEBUG   (   34):     r4 00000048  r5 00000001  r6 4d960528  r7 00000018
I/DEBUG   (   34):     r8 4d960c28  r9 4d860fb8  sl 2a20bc08  fp 4d95ea98
I/DEBUG   (   34):     ip 4d422f20  sp 4d95e9e8  lr 4d41d637  pc 40034e4c  cpsr 20000010
I/DEBUG   (   34):     d0  417654683f800000  d1  417654683f800000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     d2  3fe7ce583f800000  d3  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     d4  0000000000000000  d5  3ff0000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     d6  3fe0000000000000  d7  3fb3bd3c01654680
I/DEBUG   (   34):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     scr 20000010
I/DEBUG   (   34): 
I/DEBUG   (   34): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (   34):     #00  pc 0000de4c  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   34):     #01  pc 00013633  /system/lib/libGLESv2_enc.so
I/DEBUG   (   34):     #02  pc 00013ad9  /system/lib/libGLESv2_enc.so (GLSharedGroup::addProgramData(unsigned int)+18)
I/DEBUG   (   34):     #03  pc 0000aa1b  /system/lib/libGLESv2_enc.so (GL2Encoder::s_glCreateProgram(void*)+20)
I/DEBUG   (   34):     #04  pc 00004eb5  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so (glCreateProgram+14)
I/DEBUG   (   34):     #05  pc 003cb690  /data/app-lib/com.indgames.rocks-2/libkglt.so (_ZN9GLChecker7CheckerIjRFjvEJEE3runES2_+16)
I/DEBUG   (   34): 
I/DEBUG   (   34): stack:
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95e9a8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95e9ac  4d95ea08  
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95e9b0  4d95e9e8  
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95e9b4  4d95e9d8  
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95e9b8  2a250568  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95e9bc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95e9c0  2a250088  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95e9c4  2a250088  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95e9c8  00000041  
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95e9cc  00000020  
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95e9d0  2a250938  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95e9d4  4d95e9a8  
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95e9d8  00000041  
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95e9dc  00000020  
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95e9e0  df0027ad  
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95e9e4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   34):     #00  4d95e9e8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95e9ec  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95e9f0  4d960528  
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95e9f4  00000018  
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95e9f8  4d960c28  
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95e9fc  4d41d637  /system/lib/libGLESv2_enc.so
I/DEBUG   (   34):     #01  4d95ea00  00000004  
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95ea04  4d41dadd  /system/lib/libGLESv2_enc.so (GLSharedGroup::addProgramData(unsigned int)+22)
I/DEBUG   (   34):     #02  4d95ea08  2a224fc0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95ea0c  00000048  
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95ea10  4d960528  
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95ea14  4d41a6d7  /system/lib/libGLESv2_enc.so (glCreateProgram_enc+46)
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95ea18  2a22b3d8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95ea1c  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95ea20  2a22b3d8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95ea24  4d960528  
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95ea28  4d9602b8  
I/DEBUG   (   34):          4d95ea2c  4d414a1f  /system/lib/libGLESv2_enc.so (GL2Encoder::s_glCreateProgram(void*)+24)
```

The first weird thing here is that the stacktrace lists GLESv2, when everywhere I'm using GLESv3, the second is that if I use ndk-gdb, I can't see the stacktrace at all...

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 968]
0x40034e4c in ?? () from /home/kazade/Git/rocks-android/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libc.so
(gdb) bt
#0  0x40034e4c in ?? () from /home/kazade/Git/rocks-android/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libc.so
#1  0x4d41d636 in ?? ()
#2  0x4d41d636 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb)
```

How can I get more debug information to work out why this crash is happening?

Also, is it normal that GL calls go through GLESv2.so even if I've specified

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" />
```

in my AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Sharing GLESv2 library file for both v2.0 and v3.0 is nothing new - v3.0 extends v2.0 after all - and though share a lot of code together. But more importantly : _uses-feature_ element does _not_ say anything about the OpenGL context version you are handed. You need to explicitly ask for v3.0 context in your code where appropriate (i.e depending on how you create one).

Answer (score 0):

I think this was something to do with SDL 2.0 not properly supporting GLES 3. Altering my code to be GLES 2 compatible made the issue go away.